# Unable to render drawer navigation in React navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

Hi Have a react navigation method which make a drawer, which is inside a createSwitchNavigator. But when doing the final call I am not able to render the drawer correctly. I am getting

Invariant violation error coming.

```
This is my drawer:
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home:{
       screen: DashboardScreen,
    },
    Notifications: {
       screen: UserMeetingScreen,
    },
  });

 const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

 export default MyApp
```

This is my stacknavigator

```
import AppStack from '../navigator/loggedIn';
import AuthStack from '../navigator/loggedOut';
import LoadingScreen from '../components/Loading/loading.component';

export const GetAppStack = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {   
        AuthLoading: LoadingScreen,
        LoggedOut: AuthStack,
        LoggedIn: AppStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
))
```

And this is my dashboard component

```
export default class DashboardScreen extends React.Component{

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerMode: 'none',
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: '#4F6D7A',
            elevation: 0
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <OfflineNotice />
                <Icon 
                name= 'flight-takeoff'
                onPress= {()=> this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
                ></Icon>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting a Element type is invalid error. Check render method of Dashboard screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `OfflineNotice`?

Comment: Offline Notice is a component to poll if the device is connected to internet

Comment: I think You OfflineNotice Screen is Bad Error

Comment: I removed it and still the same error

Comment: create a simple snack here https://snack.expo.io, might get a quick response.

Comment: You need to export the `createDrawerNavigator` instead of `createAppContainer` from your LoginStack; try that and let me know if it works :-)